# Networksite/multisite is disabled ?, Why?

Tags: multisite

[image]

*/

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mrbrain.in');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

How to enable the network tab in my website, I cant change my theme and etc..